# NGINX - Two different rails apps under same domain

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have two different Rails (passenger) apps that I wan to host on one server:

```
somehost.com/      <-- App #1
somehost.com/admin <--- App #2
```

Tried playing with the 'location' directive, but failed to have both operate.

Can someone suggest the correct approach ?

(I would prefer both to share same environment, only launch from different directories)

EDIT: Sample (desired) config

Trying to do something like:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myhost.com;
   rails_env production;
   passenger_enabled on;

  location / {
    root /opt/main_site/public/;
  }

  location /dev {
    root /opt/admin_site/public/;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you actually try to do with the location directives?  Can you post that?

Something like:

```
  location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://app2;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app1;
  }
```

should work.

Comment: I added a sample config